# SQL 2005 - Table valued function compiles ok but throws Incorrect syntax near .. when selected

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, oracle10g

This table valued function compiles ok,

```
alter function [dbo].[ftsls031nnnHades](@withExpiredEntries smallint ) returns 
@t table( comno     varchar(3), 
        t$cuno      varchar(6),
        t$cpgs      varchar(6),
        t$dile      float,
        t$qanp      float,
        t$stdt      varchar(10),
        t$tdat      varchar(10),
        t$disc      float,
        t$damt      float,
        t$cdis      char(3),
        t$gnpr      float,
        t$refcntd   float,
        t$refcntu   float) as
------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------
declare @withExpiredEntries bit; set @withExpiredEntries =0
declare @t table( comno     varchar(3), 
        t$cuno      varchar(6),
        t$cpgs      varchar(6),
        t$dile      float,
        t$qanp      float,
        t$stdt      varchar(10),
        t$tdat      varchar(10),
        t$disc      float,
        t$damt      float,
        t$cdis      char(3),
        t$gnpr      float,
        t$refcntd   float,
        t$refcntu   float)
------------------------------------------------------*/
Begin
set quoted_identifier off
if (@withExpiredEntries = 0) -- without expired entries
    Begin
        insert @t
        select * 
        from openQuery(Hades ,"select '010' comno, trim(t$cuno) t$cuno,trim(t$cpgs) t$cpgs,t$dile,t$qanp,to_char(t$stdt,'dd Mon yy') t$stdt,to_char(t$tdat,'dd Mon yy') t$tdat,to_char(t$disc,'999.99') t$disc,t$damt,t$cdis,t$gnpr,t$refcntd,t$refcntu from baan.ttdsls031010 where (to_char(t$Tdat,'yyyy-mm-dd') >= To_char(current_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')) and (to_char(t$stdt,'yyyy-mm-dd') <= To_char(current_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')) 
               union all       select '020' comno, trim(t$cuno) t$cuno,trim(t$cpgs) t$cpgs,t$dile,t$qanp,to_char(t$stdt,'dd Mon yy') t$stdt,to_char(t$tdat,'dd Mon yy') t$tdat,to_char(t$disc,'999.99') t$disc,t$damt,t$cdis,t$gnpr,t$refcntd,t$refcntu from baan.ttdsls031020 where (to_char(t$tdAt,'yyyy-mm-dd') >= To_char(current_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')) and (to_char(t$stdt,'yyyy-mm-dd') <= To_char(current_date,'yyyy-mm-dd'))")
    return  
End
    insert @t
    select * 
        from openQuery(Hades ,"select '010' comno, trim(t$cuno) t$cuno,trim(t$cpgs) t$cpgs,t$dile,t$qanp,to_char(t$stdt,'dd Mon yy') t$stdt,to_char(t$tdat,'dd Mon yy') t$tdat,to_char(t$disc,'999.99') t$disc,t$damt,t$cdis,t$gnpr,t$refcntd,t$refcntu from baan.ttdsls031010  
               union all       select '020' comno, trim(t$cuno) t$cuno,trim(t$cpgs) t$cpgs,t$dile,t$qanp,to_char(t$stdt,'dd Mon yy') t$stdt,to_char(t$tdat,'dd Mon yy') t$tdat,to_char(t$disc,'999.99') t$disc,t$damt,t$cdis,t$gnpr,t$refcntd,t$refcntu from baan.ttdsls031020   ")
    return
end
```

it throws this error when selected

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'select '010' comno, trim(t$cuno) t$cuno,trim(t$cpgs) t$cpgs,t$dile,t$qanp,to_char(t$stdt,'dd Mon yy') t$stdt,to_char(t$tdat,'dd '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change double quote to single quote and see what happens...

```
...
..Hades ,'select '010' comno...
...
```

You'll also have to double up the contained singles too.

When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON, " delimits an object/column name etc. Not a string. This is the default setting too.

The [SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF has no meaning at runtime](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx): it's set at CREATE/ALTER time... this is why you get the error at runtime not CREATE time. CREATE <> compile by the way... it's compiled to a plan at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on Quoted_identifer.. 
I did alter the select statment to flip single and double quotes with each other.. but still the same..

Comment: TonyP: I mean double up that is '' not "